# Arbitrage opportunity in discrete time

Tags: options, option-pricing, arbitrage, binary-options

Say we have the following binary option $B$ on asset $S$ with strike K and expiration time T, assume also that the following relation holds at time $0$:

$B > N*C(K,T)-N*C(K+1/N,T)$

Where $N$ is some natural number and $C(K,T)$ is the call option on asset $S$ with strike K and expiration time T

How is it possible to find an arbitrage  strategy in that case , under the assumption that we can buy call options at any strike?

Comment: 1) is B an up or a down binary option ?
2) right hand side is negative

Comment: 1) up binary option 2) edited

Comment: Your inequality is always true, and then it is difficult to find an arbitrage opportunity, unless you change your inequality to $B <  N*C(K,T)-N*C(K+1/N,T)$ or  $B >  N*C(K-1/N,T)-N*C(K,T)$

Comment: Thanks @Gordon is it possible in case $B <  N*C(K,T)-N*C(K+1/N,T)$?

Comment: The argument in that case is similar.

Comment: @Gordon , please see my comment below your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume that the inequality is given by
\begin{align*}
B > N C(K-1/N, T) - N  C(K, T).\tag{1}
\end{align*}
The argument for the case with the inequality
\begin{align*}
B < N C(K, T) - N C(K+1/N, T) 
\end{align*}
is similar.
 $$$$
For the binary option,
\begin{align*}
\pmb{1}_{\{S_T \ge K\}} = 
\begin{cases}
1, & \textrm{if } S_T \ge K,\\
0, & \textrm{otherwise},
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
while for the portfolio with payoff
\begin{align*}
X_T &= N\bigg[S_T-\Big(K-\frac{1}{N}\Big)\bigg]^+ - N (S_T-K)^+\\
&=
\begin{cases}
1, & \textrm{if } S_T \ge K,\\
N\bigg[S_T-\Big(K-\frac{1}{N}\Big)\bigg], & \textrm{if } K-\frac{1}{N} \le S_T \le K,\\
0, & \textrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then, it is obvious that
\begin{align*}
\pmb{1}_{\{S_T \ge K\}} \le X_T,\tag{2}
\end{align*}
and, consequently,
\begin{align*}
B \le N C(K-1/N, T) -N  C(K, T).
\end{align*}

$$$$
However, if (1) holds, we can then short the binary option, short $N$ units call option with strike $K$, and long $N$ units call option with strike $K-1/N$. We have a net profit 
\begin{align*}
B - \big[N C(K-1/N, T) - N  C(K, T)\big].
\end{align*} 
Moreover, at maturity $T$, we have the portfolio payoff 
\begin{align*}
X_T - \pmb{1}_{\{S_T \ge K\}} \ge 0,
\end{align*}
as per (2) above.

Comment: In case $B <  N*C(K,T)-N*C(K+1/N,T)$  and doing a similar strategy we will not earn at time $T$ in case $K<S_T<K+1/N$ since we short the binary option and loss 1 while the profit from the rest is smaller then 1

Comment: @pointiy: In this case, we short $N$ units call options with strike $K$ and long  $N$ units call options with strike $K+1/N$, and short the binary option.

Comment: I still don't understand how in that case we have profit in case $K<S_T<K+1/N$.

Comment: Sorry @pointiy: In this case, we short $N$ units call options with strike, long $N$ units call options with strike $K+1/N$, and long (NOT short)  the binary option.